# tableView not updating after adding Core Data object

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data, tableview

Given this Core Data Model: Photographer <-->>Photos.

After adding a Photographer via a Modal View, the tableView of Photographers updates accordingly.

The problem is, that it doesn't do the same for Photos. I can add a Photo via a Modal View, and the tableView of Photos for that particular Photographer does not update immediately.  Once I navigate back to the tableView of Photographers and select the same Photographer again, it updates as expected.

How can I get the tableView of Photos to update as soon as the Modal View(where the user added the object) gets dismissed?

Answer (score 1):

Where modal view dismiss try to use:

```
[tableView reloadData];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 [tableview reload];
```

method after getting new data.

Comment: already included in my viewWillAppear for the Photos TableViewController. And I have confirmed that my viewWillAppear is being called.

Comment: photographerPhotosList is my tableView

Comment: where are you getting new data after assigning at viewWillAppear method?

Comment: I have realized that tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: on the Photo TableViewController is only getting called when pushing to it from the Photographer TableViewController, and not when dismissing from the Modal View - how do I fix that?(Mind you, viewWillAppear is getting called in both scenarios.)

Comment: what i mean to say is that when the tableView of Photos for the particular Photographer gets new data at that time immidiately you have to reload your table

Comment: Are you saying that the `[tableView reloadData];` should be called form the Modal View? I tried that using a singleton, and it didn't work.

Comment: i think your photographerPhotosArray is not updating at Modal View...try to update it and then reload the table....

Comment: I added it into my photographerPhotosArray via the Modal View and its stil not working.  The tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath is still not getting called when dismissing the Modal View.

Comment: Just for the sake of anyone else stumbles upon this later on, turns out the issue was that my TableView in IB was linked to a NSMutableArray - not the tableView itself. Happened to run across this trying to fix another issue - and it fixed both. Thanks for the answers @Stark and others.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check your error variable if it contains an error.
2. You directly assign the result of -executeFetchRequest:error: to an ivar (photographerPhotosArray). This either leaks or causes an immediate release.
3. Consider switching to NSFetchedResultsController since it helps you a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Check your array first is it fill or empty? try with NSLog and check it. if it exist then reload your table